# Nginx: set Content-Type by URI problem

Tags: url-rewriting, cache, nginx, content-type

I'm setting up small personal file hosting, I made a backend to store uploaded files by their hash directly on the HDD like `/f/ab/cd/ef012345678...`, but without file extensions and generate an URI like `example.com/f/ab/cd/ef012345678.../filename.jpg`.

Nginx serves the files right from HDD using this config:

```
location /f {
     rewrite "^/f/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)(.*)$" /$1/$2/$3 break;
     root /srv/cdn/f;
}
```

I.e. it cuts the last part of the URI and reads the file using only it's hash. It works well, but it strips file's mime types to `application/octet-stream` which forces browser to download all files, but it to display images inlined.

I made a workaround by including in this location a piece of config like this:

```
if ($request_uri ~* \.png$) {
    add_header Content-Type "image/png";
}
```

Which fixes the problem for Google Chrome and for the first load in Firefox.

But when I open the link the second time in Firefox or just reload the page, it prompts me to download it. Apparently, Firefox is handling Content-Type with 304 answer poorly (I checked headers, Nginx sends 304 response and Content-Type header with this configuration if file was pulled from the cache).

**I'm looking for way to either determine in Nginx config if the file was server from cache and not add the header of for better *Nginx* solution.**

*I know the better idea is to change my backend and add file extensions, it will solve some future problems too, but now I can't sleep and need to know the answer using Nginx only if there is one.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this method works and your `rewrite...break` method does not. But you can capture the regular expression in the `location` statement and use that in an `alias` expression, and it seems to leave the `Content-Type` as per the original request URI.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/(f/[a-z0-9]+/[a-z0-9]+/[a-z0-9]+) {
    alias /srv/cdn/$1;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for more.

Note that regular expression `location` statements are ordered, so its position within your configuration file may be significant. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

Comment: Wow, that actually works! Thanks. Makes me want to find why now :D I just assumed it won't work the same way as `try_files` and `rewrite` don't - they get mime type by _file's_ extension, not URI.

Comment: `rewrite` and `try_files` changes `$uri` which is probably why the effective file extension changes.